# How to get object list from objects that's got two nested objects in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, groovy

I have a Product, Location and ProductLocation table. After retrieving a Location object I wish to get a list of all products that belong to this location. I have tried setting up a criteria but it's returning ProductLocation object instead of a Product list. My question is how can I get a list of products from the ProductLocation objects?

```
List<Product> findByLocation(Location location){

        def criteria = ProductLocation.where {
            eq('location', location)

        }
        criteria.list()
    }



class Product {

        String title
        String imagepath
        String description
        Category category

        static belongsTo = [locations: Location]

        static mapping = {
            version false
        }

    static constraints = {
        title nullable: false
        imagepath nullable: false
        description nullable: true
    }

    static hasMany = [locations: Location]


}

class ProductLocation {

    Product product
    Location location


    static mapping = {
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {

    }

    static belongsTo = [products: Product, locations: Location]


}

class Location  {

    Company customer
    Location parent
    String name
    String description
    String objectnumber
    String address
    String zipcode
    String province
    String city
    String country
    Long longitude
    Long latitude
    Integer order
    String timezone
    AlertConfiguration alertConfiguration
    boolean deleted
    LocationType type


    static hasMany = [products: Product]

    static mapping = {

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
List<Product> findByLocation(Location location){
    ProductLocation.createCriteria().list {
        eq('location', location)
        projections {
            property( 'product' )
        }
    }
}
```